How to create a dynamic seat layout in the NextJS app
I'm working on a booking app in Nextjs. I want to create a seat layout for booking tickets. I had read many questions on StackOverflow but didn't get any ideas. Can anyone help me on "How can I create a seat booking layout?". I have attached a screenshot of the layout below. You have to consider only yellow and white colors. The description are below.

Yellow use for show Booked Ticket.
White use for available tickets.
The layout will be changed based on theatre.



the question is too broad and it's not a next js specific problem. First of all, the layout can be done in pure HTML and looping. As for the rest. you can ask again after implement the UI first

Please update the question above with these details. Explain the meaning of colors : white, yellow, orange, black & red Slashed/Cross seats. Explain the possible values of those seats Allotted, Unallotted, Unavailable etc. ?

I have added description about color.
